# Git submodules committing without me knowing..?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, pull-request

Some personal background: I've used git submodules before, but to be honest I'm not a fan and entirely accept this maybe my ignorance of the nuances of how they work.  When I've used them before for shared libraries, I pulled updates with a `git pull` in the submodule, which then showed as `modified … (new commits)` in the parent.  I get this - I've changed the commit pointer in the `.git` metadata, or something along those lines, and I need to `commit` and `push` that change in the parent repo so it's associated with the right submodule commit.

My problem: I'm now in a new job, and the project I work on has a submodule. It's not a shared library - the build process relies on some credentials that, for security reasons, are updated daily and distributed via the submodule. So there is a daily process of pulling updates, which happens by `git submodule update --remote`.

Two oddities: (1) the submodule is perpetually in a detached-head state; and (2) the `status` of the parent remains clean, showing no change to the submodule.

So why is this a problem? The problem is, my pull requests are showing up with the submodule in the "changed files" list. I don't think this actually results in a problem, but one peer-reviewer takes particular exception to these changes, as they shouldn't be there. Since the submodule never shows up as modified in `git status` output, I'm not aware of how I'm committing any change, and so how to stop this.

(This is a private repo in GitHub - I have a fork, and am working in a branch of my fork. The submodule remains pointed at the un-forked master for its repo.)

(Apparently this is also apparent in some other developers' PRs, but not in every PR.)

I'm new to this company, and could do without being painted as someone who can't work version control properly! But I need someone with more git-wisdom than I to tell me what's going on.

(Personally, my solution would be *not to use a submodule*, not this might not be within my control.)

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: there's probably nothing wrong here, except for a grumpy reviewer. :-)  You can make him happier if you change your `git add` process a bit or fuss with your PR building, but it might be better to make him less grumpy about the updates, or, indeed, not use submodules at all (but both of these are more of a team discussion item).  You can skip down to the section on the submodule update process if most of the long section below is familiar.

## Long

Submodules are fundamentally a little bit klunky and there will always be some issues around them.

First, let's just address these:

> the submodule is perpetually in a detached-head state

This is normal.  A detached HEAD just means *I'm not on any branch, I have a specific commit checked-out instead,* and it's normal for a submodule to not be on any branch like this.

> the `status` of the parent remains clean, showing no change to the submodule

This is also normal enough (we'll see details in a moment).  Neither is related (directly at least) to your PR issue.

#### The submodule is its own Git repository

Now, let's address this part:

> there is a daily process of pulling updates, which happens by `git submodule update --remote`

If we consult [the `git submodule` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html), we find that this subcommand is documented (not very well) in a section under the `--remote` option:

> > This option is only valid for the `update` command. Instead of using
> >     the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the
> >     status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch. The remote used
> >     is branch’s remote (`branch.<name>.remote`), defaulting to `origin`.
> >     The remote branch used defaults to `master`, but the branch name may
> >     be overridden by setting the `submodule.<name>.branch` option in
> >     either `.gitmodules` or `.git/config` (with `.git/config` taking
> >     precedence).
> >
> > This works for any of the supported update procedures ...  The only change is the source of the target SHA-1 ... [snip]

There is a lot to unpack here.  Let's start with the easiest bit: a submodule is a Git repository in its own right, with branch names, tag names, a `HEAD`, an index, a work-tree, and so on.  Hence there are two Git repositories: one for the superproject (which lists the submodule as a repository to use), and one for the submodule itself.  The submodule *does not list anything special.*  The only special items are these, which are a consequence of the superproject Git doing some fiddling before it does any cloning or `git checkout`-ing:

- the `.git` (or `$GIT_DIR`) directory containing the actual submodule tends to live within the superproject's `.git` directory;<sup>1</sup>
- the work-tree for the submodule lives at the path determined by the superproject; and
- the *commit* that the superproject Git checks out, and/or thinks is correct, for the submodule is—usually, anyway—determined by a *hash ID recorded in the superproject*.

**This last item is the source of the detached HEAD.**  The step that extracts the submodule into its work-tree runs `git checkout hash-ID`, where the *`hash-ID`* initially comes from a superproject commit.  Running `git submodule update --remote` has the superproject Git tell the subproject Git:

- first, run `git fetch`, so that we can see if there is a new commit hash for your branch;
- then if there *is* a new commit hash, run `git checkout hash` to switch to it.

This, of course, *also* results in a detached HEAD.  The most curious part is the step described as *see if there is a new commit hash for your branch* because *the submodule is not on a branch!*  It has a detached HEAD instead.  If you're saying "WTF" to yourself here, you're on the right track (no pun intended).  The last paragraph under `--remote` has the answer:

> > ... `update --remote` uses ... `submodule.<name>.branch` [to figure out the branch name for the submodule, and hence whether there's a new commit hash, and if so, passes it to `git checkout`.]

(You can have `update --remote` use any of checkout, merge, or rebase.  When using the latter two, it's more complicated.  We don't need any more complication, so let's stick with the `checkout` case.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This feature was new in Git 2.12, when "absorbgitdirs" was added.  Previously, the `.git` for the submodule was located at the root of the submodule's work-tree.  Now what happens is that the submodule Git writes a *file* named `.git` at the root of its work-tree.  The `.git` file directs the submodule Git to look inside the superproject's `.git` directory, so that it can see that it's a submodule of a superproject.

---

#### Superproject commits record submodule hash IDs

There's a general rule about commits in Git repositories, which applies to all repositories and all commits: they are all complete snapshots of everything.  That's true for the submodule repository—each commit is a complete snapshot of all files—and also for the superproject.  Instead of recording the submodule's *files*, however, the superproject commits record the submodule's *hash ID*.

The mechanism behind this is Git's *index*.  Except for `--bare` repositories (these have *no* work-tree), a Git repository comes with one index and one work-tree.  The index holds a copy of every file that came out of the *current* commit, and which will go into the *next* commit you make.

The saved files inside the repository, as recorded by each commit, are stored in a special, compressed (sometimes highly compressed), Git-only format.  Once in a commit, these files are entirely read-only as well, which means a new commit can just re-use the old file from an older commit if you have not changed it.  That's a big reason why, even though every commit stores every file, the repository does not grow rapidly: the new commits are really just re-using the old commits' files.

Of course, files that are read-only can't be modified, and files that are in a Git-only form can't be used by anything but Git.  So Git has to expand these read-only, Git-only files that Git stores with the commits, into read/write, ordinary-format files that you can use.  Those read/write, ordinary-format files go into your work-tree.

Most version control systems stop here: there are permanent, read-only, frozen, compressed files in the repository, and temporary, read/write files in your work-tree that you work with.  To make a new commit, the VCS compresses every work-tree file all over again and checks to see if it's already in the repository.  If so, it re-uses the old one; if not, it puts the new one in; either way the new commit refers to the new file, even if that's just the old file.  But this is horribly slow.

What Git does instead is to thaw out, but keep as compressed and Git-only, *every file from the current commit*.  Those go into the index.  Then Git forces *you*, the programmer, to `git add` each file when you change it: this re-compresses the file into the Git-only format and copies it into the index, overwriting the previous index copy if there was one, or creating the file from scratch if it's all-new.  Either way, the index is *ready to go*, to make the new commit, so `git commit` is blazingly fast: it just has to freeze all the already-prepared files.

This is why the index can be described as *the next commit you will make, if you run `git commit` right now*.  (It also has several other other useful functions.  So the fact that Git has the index all up in your face, making you `git add` into it all the time, may be annoying, but also can be useful.  But this aspect—*index = next commit*—is the key one.)

That's fine for files, but what about for submodules?  Well, the submodule information that is in the superproject *commit* is the hash ID that the submodule is supposed to `git checkout`.  So Git stores that in the commit *and* in the index as well.  The *next* commit you make will have this submodule hash in it.

#### The submodule update process

An initial checkout (`git submodule update --init`, for instance) just checks out the specific commit, as we saw earlier.  This puts the correct commit into the submodule, and also has the correct commit *hash* in the superproject's index:

```
Submodule path 'sub': checked out '8ffac73422c73898facacb7a0f92ed15a29cc7ad'
```

My submodule Git is now in detached HEAD state.  The `HEAD` commit in my superproject shows that the correct submodule commit is `8ffac73422c73898facacb7a0f92ed15a29cc7ad`, and the index says to use that commit:<sup>2</sup>

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD:sub
8ffac73422c73898facacb7a0f92ed15a29cc7ad
$ git rev-parse :0:sub
8ffac73422c73898facacb7a0f92ed15a29cc7ad
```

When you run `git submodule update --remote`, and that checks out some new commit, that *does not* record the new submodule hash ID, it just checks it out.  Here I've updated the submodule's remote repository, so that `git submodule update --remote` finds a new hash ID for `master` in the submodule (there is only one submodule branch so everything is automatically `master`):

```
$ git submodule update --remote
Submodule path 'sub': checked out 'ca09e95a23e28ef71765113ea0caef2bd7ce9594'
```

Now the *submodule* is on that commit:

```
$ (cd sub; git rev-parse HEAD)
ca09e95a23e28ef71765113ea0caef2bd7ce9594
```

However, the *superproject* that I am in still calls for the other commit:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   sub (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The `git diff` command, which compares the index to the work-tree, says:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/sub b/sub
index 8ffac73..ca09e95 160000
--- a/sub
+++ b/sub
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 8ffac73422c73898facacb7a0f92ed15a29cc7ad
+Subproject commit ca09e95a23e28ef71765113ea0caef2bd7ce9594
```

I can now run `git add sub` and `git commit` to make a new commit that's almost exactly the same as my old commit, except that the hash ID it tells Git to extract, if I were to run `git submodule update`—*without* `--remote`—is now `ca09e95a23e28ef71765113ea0caef2bd7ce9594`:

```
$ git add sub
$ git commit -m 'update submodule'
[master fd09d9b] update submodule
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

If I had had other changed or new files, I would have had to `git add` them as well, to copy them into the index so that they went into the new commit.

Note that if I carefully *avoid* `git add sub`—and also things like `git add -a` or `git add -u`, which would update `sub`—then any *new* commit I make will *not* have the new hash ID for `sub`, but rather will have the *old* hash ID for `sub`.  If someone checks out that particular commit, and then runs `git submodule update` (without `--remote` again), their superproject Git will tell their submodule Git to check out the *old* commit, not the new one.

It's also possible, if you've accidentally `git add`ed sub, to use `git reset` to set it back before committing:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   sub (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git add sub   # oops!
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   sub

$ git reset sub
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       sub
```

Now, even though the submodule itself is on `ca09e95a23e28ef71765113ea0caef2bd7ce9594`, the index in the superproject still says `8ffac73422c73898facacb7a0f92ed15a29cc7ad`.

---

<sup>2</sup>These names, `HEAD:sub` and `:0:sub`, are [gitrevisions syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for specifying particular objects.  The `git rev-parse` command turns them into the hash IDs for the underlying Git object.  In this case, that is the tree or index hash ID for the submodule.

---

#### On pull requests

Git itself does not have pull requests.<sup>3</sup>  These are instead a feature of web sites like GitHub.  All Git really has are commits, stored in repositories.  To *create* a pull request on GitHub:

1. You must `git push` your actual commits to some actual repository.  This can be the main one, or an auxiliary one you created using the GitHub "fork a repository" button.  Git needs your commits to be connected, somehow, to this main repository.  The main one of course *is* the main one—that's pretty well connected!—and GitHub's "fork" button makes a behind-the-scenes link *from* your fork *to* the main one, so either will serve.
2. Now that your commits are on GitHub somewhere, either in or linked-to the main repository, you use more GitHub web interface clicky buttons to select a specific branch *in* the main repository.  GitHub then attempts, behind the scenes, to do a `git merge`<sup>4</sup> using a GitHub-specific reference name.  If the merge goes well, GitHub presents the pull request to whoever operates the main repository, allowing *them* to use clicky buttons on the web interface to do the merge.

So, what you get via this pull request is, in effect, the ability for *someone else* to repeat a `git merge` that you invoked.  What that `git merge` will do is easy for you to tell: you can do the `git merge` on your own.  So the pull request will change the submodule hash if and only if a `git merge` also changes the submodule hash successfully.  It could do nothing.  It could even get a merge conflict on the submodule hash!

So: When will a `git merge` change the submodule hash?  That's the same as when a `git merge` will change any other file.  What `git merge` does is find the merge base commit, then run, in effect, *two* `git diff` commands: one to compare the merge base to the tip of the branch you're merging *into*, and one to compare the merge base to the tip of the branch you're merging *from*.  Git then applies both sets of changes to all the changed files, starting with the files from the merge base.

Let's say you're merging `develop`, where you did your work, into `master` (via `git checkout master && git merge develop`).  Note that `--ours` is now the `master` branch and its commit, while `--theirs` is your commit: you've switched roles, to be the one who's going to click the GitHub "merge" button later.  The three interesting commits, then, are:

- the tip of `master`: this is the left side, or local, or `--ours` commit;
- the tip of `develop`: this is the right side, or remote, or other, or `--theirs` commit; and
- the merge base (whatever hash ID `git merge-base --all master develop` prints, assuming it prints just one hash ID).

If base-vs-`master` *does not* change the submodule hash, but base-vs-`develop` *does* change the submodule hash, the merge will succeed *and* change the submodule hash: the merge picks up their (your) change.

If base-vs-`master` *does* change the submodule hash, but base-vs-`develop` *does not* change the submodule hash, the merge will succeed and keep the `master` hash: the merge does not pick up their (your) change since there is no such change.

If base-vs-`master` *does* change the submodule hash *and* base-vs-`develop` *also* changes the submodule hash, they had better both change the hash *to* the same hash.  If so, the changes match and Git takes the one change.  If not, the changes clash, and Git declares a merge conflict and stops (or, GitHub makes a pull request that can't be merged).

So, the trick here, if you want to *not* offer a change to the submodule hash ID, is to make sure that your pull request commit—the one that will be the `--theirs` commit when it comes time to merge—uses the same submodule hash as in the merge base, whatever commit that may be.  Note that the merge base of `master` and `develop` depends on the commit hashes stored in `master` and `develop`.  If `master` is changing over time—as it often is—it's possible that the merge base hash you compute on Tuesday is wrong on Wednesday.  Hence, to some extent—really, a pretty big extent—chasing the merge base's commit hash for the submodule is a pointless errand.  It's only required if there will be a merge conflict, and in that case, it's *easier* to just grab the `master` commit's hash ID directly, so that the two changes—base-vs-master and base-vs-develop—are *the same* change.

In the end, that means that these hash ID clashes, if and when they occur, are usually just a minor nuisance.  You can attempt to avoid having your commits update the submodule hash ID (ever) by avoiding `git add`ing the submodule, or by `git reset`-ing it if you accidentally added it.  (You must also avoid `git commit -a` which will add it, then commit, without giving you a chance to reset it.)

---

<sup>3</sup>Git has a command, `git request-pull`, that builds an *email message* suggesting that someone use `git pull` or `git fetch` to obtain commits from a repository you control.  To use this command, you put the commits into your repository, make your repository available to the someone else(s), build the email message, and send it to those someone else(s).  It's then up to them to run `git fetch` or `git pull` manually, using your repository URL from *their* end.

(The GitHub clicky button interface is a lot simpler for most people to use.)

<sup>4</sup>Technically, GitHub have to do something special here, because all of their repositories are `--bare` repositories, with no work-tree.  The `git merge` command won't run without a work-tree.  But they are doing the merge in a special way anyway and are not going to resolve any conflicts, so they only care about ones that can run to completion automatically.  If you do a `git merge` in your own, non-bare, repository, and it completes automatically, GitHub's will also complete automatically and do the same thing yours did.

Comment: Thank you very much taking the time to explain this in so much detail. This would all make sense apart from one thing...
**git status**
On branch issue10793
nothing to commit, working directory clean

**git submodule update --remote**
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
From https://github.com/*upstream*/settings
   6a1731d..a999466  master     -> origin/master
Submodule path 'settings': checked out 'a999466916ecc4cb4fd935b1707c55fd0e482fc9'

**git status**
On branch issue10793
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Why no "modified: settings (new commits)"?

Comment: That does seem odd. What version of Git are you using? What do you get if you `git rev-parse` the HEAD and index values of `settings` and what do you get if you do `(cd settings; git rev-parse HEAD)`?  Are you using `--ignore-submodules` in your `git status` command, and/or do you have various values set for `diff.ignoreSubmodules` and/or `status.submoduleSummary` and/or `submodule.<name>.ignore` (in this case `submodule.settings.ignore`)? I tested the above with a default-config Git 2.19.1.

Comment: Note also that you will also get no `git status` output if your branch's submodule commit matches the master branch's submodule commit *and* your submodule is actually on that commit, but your pull request would show, as a *diff*, that you're asking to update the submodule to the latest. That is, the *merge base* commit calls for submodule $old, but both the tip of master and your branch tip commit call for submodule $new. The merge succeeds because you and they both make the *same* change, but the pull request will show a change. But the above does seem odd, [continued]

Comment: ... does seem odd, since at least *one* of your two `git status` commands should have said something.

Comment: For that test, 2.5.3.windows.1 - not the only version I use, but I wanted to use the same version I use for other projects, to eliminate OS and git version as a difference. I'm also doing this with a newer git and on Linux. `rev-parse` gives me the same hash as in the check-out output. I do another update, same deal, and `rev-parse` gives me the new hash. `ignore=all` in the `.gitmodules`... which is different to my own project... is that it?

Comment: It's probably the `ignore=all`, yes.